# netlogo change color of a link line

Tags: netlogo

The color of a link line seems to be gray how could I change it? (global?)
I searched already at the netlogo dict http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html but didn't found anything about it.

Comment: `color` is a built-in variable of links just as it is the case for turtles, [see here](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#builtinvariables). So a simple `ask links [set color red]` should do the trick.

Comment: Dave is absolutely right here. Dave, you should put your response as an answer so that it can be marked correct, and so that this question shows up as answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`color` is a built-in variable of links just as it is the case for turtles, [see here](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#builtinvariables).

So this will change the color for all links:

```
ask links [set color red]
```